# How to find a column that meets the frequency of another column of varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the class numbers that has at least two male students. In this table, both classes (15033 & 15031) meet this criteria so both should pop up. I've tried this query but I cannot tell if this query would ONLY give me the correct answer if the class has exactly 2 males, but not more than 2 if that was case; if this is correct.

```sql
SELECT class, COUNT(*)  
                                 
FROM students

GROUP BY class

HAVING COUNT(2) and sgender = "M";
```

**Students** table

```
sno sname gender sbday      class

108 Peter   M   1997-09-01  15033

105 Gary    M   1995-10-02  15031

101 Alex    M   1996-02-20  15033

103 Quincy  M   1994-06-03  15031

107 Lily    F   1996-01-23  15033

109 Eva     F   1995-02-10  15031
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` *expression* in the `HAVING` clause make sure there are exactly 2 M.

```
SELECT class, COUNT(*)  
FROM students
GROUP BY class
HAVING SUM(case when sgender = "M" then 1 else 0 end) >= 2
```

Or, simply

```
SELECT class, COUNT(*)  
FROM students
WHERE sgender = "M" 
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: My goal is to find the classes that have at least 2 males; so I want the case when there is 3 or more males for the class to show up

Answer (score 0):

**Agree with @jarlh 's answer**

but if you like the cte version, is

*Updated to include where clause*

```
;With CTE AS
(
 SELECT class, COUNT(sno) AS [NoOfStudents]
 FROM Students
 WHERE sgender = 'M'
 GROUP BY class
) SELECT class FROM CTE WHERE NoOfStudents >= 2
```